# solve $x^4 + y^4 = x^3 + y^3 + 10$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory

solve $x^4 + y^4 = x^3 + y^3 + 10$  for  $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I tried solving this by trying to find upper bounds for $|x|$ and $|y|$, therefor it is quite useful to write:

$x^4 + y^4 - x^3 - y^3 = .....$

where ... is in the form of a square.

I tried to write $x^4 - x^3 = x^2(x^2+x) = x^2((x+\frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{1}{4})$, but the $'\frac{1}{4}'$ is kind of troublesome, any tips or hints on how to get a good square, so i can estimate my polynomial?

Kees

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x^4-x^3$, and $y^4-y^3$, are never negative and rarely less than $10$.  There must be very few possibilities to check.

Comment: wow it is actually pretty easy thanks xD